# Converting Sql query to spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have sql query which I want to convert to spark-scala

```
SELECT aid,DId,BM,BY 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT aid,DId,BM,BY,TO FROM SU WHERE cd =2) t 
GROUP BY aid,DId,BM,BY HAVING COUNT(*) >1;
```

SU is my Data Frame. I did this by

```
sqlContext.sql("""
  SELECT aid,DId,BM,BY 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT aid,DId,BM,BY,TO FROM SU WHERE cd =2) t 
  GROUP BY aid,DId,BM,BY HAVING COUNT(*) >1
""")
```

Instead of that I need this in utilizing my dataframe

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Comment: if SU is your dataframe, to use in way you mentioned first you need to register it as a temp table  SU.registerTempTable("table_name") and use this table name in your query.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth `val GP = SU.groupBy("aid","DId","BM","BY").agg(countDistinct("aid","DId","BM","BY","TO").alias("count") > 1 ).show`  . Had registered as temp table but I don't want to use sql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the DataFrame equivalent:

```
SU.filter($"cd" === 2)
  .select("aid","DId","BM","BY","TO")
  .distinct()
  .groupBy("aid","DId","BM","BY")
  .count()
  .filter($"count" > 1)
  .select("aid","DId","BM","BY")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked fine... But the query is taking long time to execute

Comment: the distinct operation is usually expensive. Also, you can look at the numbers of shuffles and try to re-modify your query to decrease the number of shuffles.